# Adding a legend to a drawArrow plot (Octave)

Tags: matlab, octave

Im trying to plot a vector diagram with several vectors.

Right now I have the following code, which draws a vector, colors it and, not successfully, adds a legend to the arrow.

```
pkg load geometry

a = drawArrow(0,0,9.94,0,1,0.1)
set(a.body, "color", "r")
set(a.wing, "color", "r")
set(a.head, "color", "r")

legend(a.body, 'Name1', 'location','northoutside','orientation','horizontal')    %DOESNT WORK
```

I tried following the documentation for the drawArrow function ([here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/drawArrow.html)) and the legend function ([here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/legend.html)), but couldn't make it work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation your syntax is correct.

The problem is that the arrow doesn't have a `head` property, and you are getting an error, before reaching the `legend` command.

The following code works:

```
pkg load geometry

a = drawArrow(0,0,9.94,0,1,0.1)
set(a.body, "color", "r")
set(a.wing, "color", "r")
%set(a.head, "color", "r")

legend(a.body, 'Name1', 'location','northoutside','orientation','horizontal')
```

Comment: Interesting, because the help for drawarrow specifically mentions body, wing and head as fields of the struct created by drawarrow. Is this a documentation bug, or did you mean that color just doesn't apply to head?

Comment: @NickJ The documentation is misleading: There is an arrow with a head and there is an arrow with a wing, but there is no arrow with both head and wing. Head or wing depends of the type of the arrow. (Head applies filled triangle and wing looks like >).